# How to arrange datatable using C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am building datatable dynamically and the format is like following,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc;

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "Question";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "User1";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "User2";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dr["Question"] = "2D";
dr["User1"] = "1";
dr["Question"] = "3D";
dr["User1"] = "4";
dr["Question"] = "2D";
dr["User2"] = "2";
dr["Question"] = "3D";
dr["User2"] = "5";
```

How can I arrange is it like following,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc;

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "Question";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "User1";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.ColumnName = "User2";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dr["Question"] = "2D";
dr["User1"] = "1";
dr["User2"] = "2";
dr["Question"] = "3D";
dr["User1"] = "4";
dr["User2"] = "5";
```

Comment: dr means new DataRow()?

Comment: Execuse me ..., I cannot see what's the difference ..

Comment: Can you please explain in details what type of arrangement are you looking for ?

Comment: Yes dr is new datarow. @KenKin, Difference is there when I want to use  dt as MSChart datasource.

Comment: But something like `dr["Question"] = "2D";` then `dr["Question"] = "3D";` just resulting `dr["Question"] = "3D";` after all.

Comment: @KenKin,Questions are grouped by user name.. When I loop with user name array it builds datatable for first user with all questions then second user and so on..

Comment: Then what is 1, 4, 2, 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make linq cross join and filter it to list (you can bind list to your msChart)

```
var result = (from dr1 in dt.Select()
                  join dr2 in dt.Select() on dr1["Question"].ToString() equals dr2["Question"].ToString()
                  select new { q = dr1["question"], u1 = dr1["User1"], u2 = dr2["User2"] }
                 ).Where(row => row.u1.ToString().Length > 0 && row.u2.ToString().Length > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you mean to use this linq code to filter entire data table and store the new result in "result" and use result as data source for MSChart ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use code similar to this;

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Question"] = "2D";
dr["User1"] = "1";
dr["User2"] = "2";

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Question"] = "3D";
dr["User1"] = "4";
dr["User2"] = "5";
```

Comment: I am building datatable from multiple sources dynamically so it's coming in the format I've mentioned above but that datatable is not working for MSChart so wanted in new format after creation.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that dr is a variable of type DataRow obtained calling the DataTable method NewRow, then you can add the values to the row [ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) property in just one line.
Of course you need to be absolutely sure of your columns order and type

```
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr.ItemArray = new object[] {"Q1", "1", "2"};
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr.ItemArray = new object[] {"Q2", "3", "4"};
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```